# ByteBuddy, Modify Sleuth SpanCustomizer using javaagent bytebuddy

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, byte-buddy, javaagents, opentracing

Have a question about modifying Sleuth SpanCustomizer, I want to customize the span name and add additional span tag.

My final goal is want to implement a class like the following code to achieve the span tag/name modification, Should I just use bytebuddy to apply this piece of class into the agent OR detect and intercept SpanCustomizer Class to do the modification?

Any advice would be helpful, Thank you!

-------------------- Final goal implement this class --------------------

```
@Configuration
public class TracingConfig{

    @Bean(name = { HttpClientRequestParser.NAME, HttpServerRequestParser.NAME })
    HttpRequestParser sleuthHttpServerRequestParser() {
        return (req, context, span) -> {
            HttpRequestParser.DEFAULT.parse(req, context, span);
            span.tag("upstream_cluster", getUpstreamCluster(req));
            span.name(getOperationName(req));
        };
    }
    @Bean(name = { HttpClientResponseParser.NAME, HttpServerResponseParser.NAME })
    HttpResponseParser sleuthHttpServerResponseParser(){
        return (resp, context, span) -> {
            HttpResponseParser.DEFAULT.parse(resp, context, span);
            span.tag("http.status_code", Integer.toString(resp.statusCode()));
            span.name(getOperationName(resp.request()));
        };
    }
}
```

My current implementation is as follows:

-------------------- Premain --------------------

```
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws Exception {

AgentBuilder.Transformer transformerHttp = new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
        @Override
        public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule module) {
            return builder
                    .method(ElementMatchers.<MethodDescription>any())
                    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MyHttpAdvice.class));
        }
    };

AgentBuilder agentBuilder = new AgentBuilder.Default();

agentBuilder = agentBuilder.type(ElementMatchers.hasSuperType(ElementMatchers.named("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"))
            .or(ElementMatchers.named("org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse"))
            .or(ElementMatchers.named("org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientRequest"))
            .or(ElementMatchers.named("org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse"))
            .or(ElementMatchers.named("org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient"))
            .or(ElementMatchers.named("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest")))
            .transform(transformerHttp);

agentBuilder.installOn(inst);
}
```

-------------------- My Http Advice --------------------

```
public class MyHttpAdvice {

@RuntimeType
public static Object intercept(@Origin Method method,
                               @AllArguments Object[] allArguments,
                               @SuperCall Callable<?> callable) throws Exception {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (Object allArgument : allArguments) {
            if (allArgument instanceof SpanCustomizer) {
                SpanCustomizer req = (SpanCustomizer) allArgument;
                req.tag("test1", "test2");
                req.name("test3");
                System.out.println("intercept http request span customizer ------- " + req.toString());
            }
            return callable.call();
        } 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If there is an SPI for customizations in an application, I would prefer this over an agent.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, The requirements is to make an agent to be able to inject to different user's microservices, then apply the metrics customization, span customization... to be able to use some platform microservice monitoring things. so I may have to make an agent to achieve this.
So My question is still:  should I use ByteBuddy to create a above TracingConfig class or Intercept SpanCustomizer class to do the modification there?